# How can I test dynamic image content with Selenium?

Tags: image, image-processing, selenium

I'm working on a project that generates dynamic images (like the content of the actual image changes depending on the parameters sent with the URL). Following in the TDD ways I would really like a way to test this process out. On the low end I would be okay with checking that a specific x-y pixel was a certain color. On the high end I would be happy if I could do a compare between two images and figure out if they were identical.

Any idea how I can test this with selenium? If not, is there a way to do it with HTMLUnit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem over here.

I think you need to use one of the language bindings of selenium (java, perl etc) and perform some calls with your favorite image processing libraries.

Here is a perl approach by @merlyn

> I set out to write a program that could find similar images, not just identical images. My selected strategy is to reduce each image to a 4-by-4 grid of RGB values, yielding a 48-number vector of values from 0 to 255.

http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col50.html

This does not use Selenium, maybe I'll do it and post it over here when I'm done.